# Lost bitcoin because of deleted receiving wallet id

Tags: transactions, wallet-recovery

Is it possible to recover the bitcoin that was sent to a wallet that generated using payeer which I deleted on accident? The transaction also shows completed from the other wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you deleted, but it looks like one of two things.

1. The wallet as listed in your software.
2. The file(s) associated with your wallet that your software uses.

If number 1, depending on the wallet, the files containing the private keys might still be on your hard drive. Look in the program folders and see what you find. Without knowing more, plus your wallet software, that's all I can give you.

If number 2, your only hope is if you have the private keys. Wallet files are just a list of private keys and portion of the blockchain. So if you don't have the private key, you have no bitcoin. If you backed up the private keys in some way, that's your answer. Create a new wallet and "sweep" the private keys into a new address.